# how to convert dict_values into a set

Tags: python-3.x, list, set

I have a `dict` that contains sets as values for each key, e.g.

```
{'key1': {8772, 9605},'key2': {10867, 10911, 10917},'key3': {11749,11750},'key4': {14721, 19755, 21281}}
```

Now I want to put each value, i.e. set of `int`s into a `set`, I am wondering what is the best way/most efficient way to do this.

```
{8772,9605,10867,10911,10917,11749,11750,14721,19755,21281}
```

I tried to retrieve the values from the `dict` using `dict.values()`, but that returns a `dict_values` object, making it a list, `list(dict.values())` gave me a list of sets, `set(list(exact_dups.values()))` threw me errors,

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

UPDATE. forgot to mention the result set also need to maintain uniqueness, i.e. no duplicates.

Comment: Do you want **all** of the values in **one** set or do you want a set for each value?

Comment: @AdiC yes it is what i want to achieve

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with `set.union()` and unpacked values:

```
set.union(*my_dict.values())
```

Or you can combine `set.union()` with `reduce`:

```
reduce(set.union, my_dict.values())
```

Comment: @deceze if all the objects happen to be `set`s, but in cases where they may not be, it's generally better (unless you really need to enforce they're sets) to initialise an empty set so it can work over arbitrary iterables - `set.union([1,2,3], [2, 3, 4])` will fail for instance...

Comment: @Jon *Iff* that is a concern, then yes.

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [set union](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union):

```
from functools import reduce

result = reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), my_dict.values(), set())
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

A sequence reduction with the set union operator (`|`, "or") will do:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

d = {'key1': {8772, 9605},'key2': {10867, 10911, 10917},'key3': {11749,11750},'key4': {14721, 19755, 21281}}
s = reduce(or_, d.values())
```

It essentially does `d['key1'] | d['key2'] | ...`.

Comment: Or:`set().union(*d.values())`... and then let the `set` builtin deal with it as it sees fit instead of constantly building and reducing into a set at a time.

Comment: Not functional enough for my taste. ;-) (In all seriousness, yes, that is probably better.)

Comment: @deceze wondering if I want to also maintain the uniqueness of the final result set, what should I do?

Comment: @daiyue Not sure what that means.

Comment: @deceze meaning `s` contains unique values/elements, just like a set

Comment: @daiyue Yeees, that's what this will do, because it's creating a union of sets, resulting in a set.

Answer (score 2):

Very **simple**, **readable**, **self-explanatory** solution without **any** imports:

```
arr = []
for key in dictionary:
    arr += list(dictionary[key])

answer = set(arr.sorted())
```

Comment: ```answer = set(sorted(arr))```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way

```
set1 = set()
for i in dict.values():
    set1.update(i)
set1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
keys_set= set()
for item in dict.values():
    keys_set.add(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can access only values as that's what OP wants and then sort it as follows :

```
dict1 = {'key1': {8772, 9605},'key2': {10867, 10911, 10917},'key3': {11749,11750},'key4': {14721, 19755, 21281}}

arr = []
for key in sorted(dict1.values()):
    arr += key


print('{', ','.join(str(n) for n in arr), '}', sep='')
```

produces,

```
{8772,9605,10867,10917,10911,11749,11750,14721,19755,21281}

[Program finished]
```

as requested by OP.