# How to add new tuples to a set based on if an element exists in another set in python

Tags: python, set, tuples

I have a catalogue of items that are allowed, say `{("a", 1, 20), ("b", 4, 50)}`
that corresponds to `(name, quantity, value)`.

and if I have the set:

```
my_set = {("a", 1, 20), ("b", 4, 50)}
```

I want to add a new item `("a", 1)` to this while also taking the other detail (value) from the catalogue, but append it to the tuple that is already there, and adding the numeric value so the quantity updates and the new set becomes this:

```
new_set = {**("a", 2, 20), **("b", 4, 50)}
```

The code I have so far is below.

```
def add_item(name, quantity, order): 
    items = []
    for item in CATALOGUE:
        items.append(item[0])
        if name in items:
            my_set.add((name,quantity))
        else:
            raise ValueError('item not in catalogue')
    return my_set
```

Is there any way I can add to this to get the desired outcome or is an entirely new approach needed?

Comment: So you want ```{("a", 1), ("b", 4, 50), ("a",2,20)}```?

Comment: @Sujay sorry it was unclear I've edited the question. What I want is {("a",2,20), ("b", 4, 50)}

Comment: Tuple are immutable, so you'll have to replace the old tuple with the new one.

Comment: Would a dictionary make more sense in this case? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. I think it would make more sense to have a dictionary where the key is the 'name.' Your value for that key could then be a tuple. Example: ```my_dict = {'a': (1,20), 'b': (4,50)}```

Comment: You might consider using a `dict` instead of a `set`: `my_dict = {"a": (1, 20), "b": (4, 50)}`. Then check if `name in my_dict`, and if it is, `my_dict[name] = (my_dict[name][0] + quantity, my_dict[name][1] + order)` or similar.

Comment: @chepner yes that's fine I'm just wondering how I can take the info from the catalogue and add the quantities together

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum Unfortunately this is a question I've been given and I have to return as a set /: that's why I'm having a hard time.

Comment: Here is a working function if you use a dict:
```my_dict = {'a': (1,20), 'b': (4,50)}
def add_item(item_dict, name, quantity=0, order=0): 
    if name in item_dict:
        my_tuple = item_dict[name]
        item_dict[name] = (my_tuple[0] + quantity, my_tuple[1] + order)
    else:
        raise ValueError('item not in catalogue')

    return item_dict


print(add_item(my_dict, 'a', quantity=1))```

Now that it works for a dict, you can follow this stack overflow about converting a dict to a set. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753399/how-to-convert-dict-values-into-a-set

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change approach to next:
`{"a":{"value":1, "count":1}, "b":{"value":2, "count":50}}`

And then you can easily update your values.

Comment: It's required for me to return it as a set. Is it possible to convert it back at the end to the same format I started with?